# Faster way to make report on huge datatable with R

Tags: pdf, optimization, r-markdown, query-optimization

I have a huge dataframe (11columns and +100k lines) that I wanna make a report on it. This report is basically a first page with some information that I saved in a .RData file and a table with ALL the values of the dataframe, coloring some of them by a condition.

I'm making this thread because rendering with RMarkDown is really slow.. I checked with a friend at work and the code is really direct, there is nowhere to optimize, I think... Is there another option for making this type of report in this conditions? I thought about html, but it need to be easily exportable, non editable and preferably printable.

Observation: I'm using the function *kable* to create the latex table.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data types are those 11 columns? If some of them are long characters or json, that could be the reason. It sounds like it might be worth preprocessing your data into smaller aggregated dataframes?

If you have to load all values in the data frame, big data type or not, that's going to take a long time to render! Is anyone running the Rmd file really going to need to interrogate the data themselves? If the answer's no, then pre-aggregate that dataframe. If the answer's yes, then you need a dashboard, not a markdown file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working from a remote folder? I just found that I moved my data to my work's server rather than my computer's desktop and the knit function has become very slow. Try bringing your files to your local computer and seeing if that helps. I see a discussion of this on the Posit support forum, but there's no resolution.